# Dependency analysis error after installing a new pod

Tags: ios, swift

Currently I'm using Swift 3, and after I install a new Pod I received this error

[image]

Here's my Pod

[image]

I can't even clean the project, I tried Pod update but the error persists. What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: You sure u opened the project by clicking workspace and not the project file itself ? Looks like various targets are inaccessible this is the common issue if you open project by clicking project file rather than opening workspace

Comment: I open the workspace

Answer (score 0):

Must Add line

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'Bolts', '~> 1.8'
    pod 'Cosmos', '~> 12.0'
end
```

Now you can install the dependencies in your project:

```
$ pod install
```